# Загрузка png изображения

Tags: gd, php

Возникла проблема при загрузке изображения формата png, с другими форматами всё нормально. Выдает такую ошибку:

> `Warning: imagepng()
> [function.imagepng]: gd-png error:
> compression level must be 0 through 9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно неправильно указан последний аргумент в вызове функции imagepng()? Он должен быть от 0 до 9.

**PS.** Выкладывайте код.

Comment: Хм, не дописал ещё один параметр в функцию, от 0 до 9 (вроде как сжатие). 
З.Ы. я думаю не у одного меня возникла проблема, при загрузке png картинки без фона, фон был НЕ прозрачным а закрашивался произвольными цветами, в общем, решение всех проблем в коде:  
    imagepng($isrc,$dest,0,PNG_NO_FILTER);